# Return HTTP Response immediately in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a WebAPI2 project doing some data collection, and I am trying to figure out how I can reduce the response time of my API methods.

I have a JavaScript function that posts information to my api. My API receives this information, inserts it in to the database, and then returns an HTTP Accepted.

Lets say there is a 5 second wait time for the data processing to be completed

```
// POST api/<controller>
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
  //This represents 5000 milliseconds of work
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

  return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);

}
```

This means, when my JavaScript function calls the Post Method, it waits 5 seconds for the response.

Is there a way I can immediately return a response of HTTP Accepted, and then continue processing my data?

**Update solution from lilo.jacob**

Ok, I've updated my method with the threading solution found below. Here is the new code

```
// POST api/<controller>
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
  new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
    {
      //This represents 5000 milliseconds of work
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }).Start();

  return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

The response is returned almost immediately, which is exactly what I was looking for.
Here are some results from Fiddler showing the change in response time
[image: Response time in Fiddler]

The first response show the lag with WebAPI on startup, requests 4,5, and 7, are using threading and fired immediately after each other. Response 11 shows the same request **without** threading enabled, notice the 5 second delay.

Very cool, clean, and lean solution to the problem.

Comment: not entirely. but what you can do is do a aync post form jquery. jquery has something called deffered and promise. may be its something that you are looking for. or if you are looking for a bulk data processing i suggest try to use a messaging framework like rabbitmq and use the queue to store long processing jobs

Comment: This may definitely become a path I need to go down. As I begin collect more information more rapidly, going directly to my API probably won't be the best choice. I'll keep rabbitmq in mind when I hit that problem. Thanks!

Comment: When you return, if the thread you started separately doesn't complete by the time you return you're in the same scenario and you've lost all of that data. This doesn't work.

Comment: You could use AMQP/ rabbitmq or kafka messaging if you want to return a quick 202 response and continue execution of code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try execute your "expensive" code in separate thread.

It will be something like this:

```
// POST api/<controller>
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
    {
        //insert to db code;
    }).Start();

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

}
```

Comment: Beautiful, this worked exactly as I expected it to, with very little effort.

Comment: @Cubix I might be nitpicking here, but you should return an HTTP 202 Accepted instead of a OK. A code 200 implies that all the work relating to the action is completed at the time of the response, whereas a code 202 means it will be processed / is processing.

Comment: Just for instance, this code is not production ready - you have to properly handling task execution, exception handling, ... In other case - if task failed there are no actual context to handle an error...

Comment: **EVERYONE PLEASE READ:** This is *not* the answer. I almost fell for this, please *don't* do this. The code could never get executed and you would never know it! This is only working by *coincidence*

Answer (score 10):

I believe [@lilo,jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23637265/538387) is not a reliable solution if the background task takes a long time. It may never be completed and you may lose data. Read this answer please:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275835/538387

Comment: I agree. The runtime can never execute the task.