# How to answer a request but continue processing code in WebApi

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I would like to answer a request, but continue processing code.

I tried something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(MyRequest sms)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Process(sms)); //need to run in a separate thread
    var response = new MyRequest(sms) { Ack = true };
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, response.ToString());
}

private async void Process(MyRequest sms)
{
    var validationResult = new MyRequestValidation(_p2pContext, _carrierService).Validate(sms);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(validationResult.Errors[0].PropertyName)) // Request not valid
        return;

    Message msg;

    if (validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        msg = await _messageService.ProcessAsync(sms);
    }
    else // Create message as finished
    {
        msg = _messageService.MessageFromMyRequest(sms,
                finished: true,
                withEventSource: validationResult.Errors[0].CustomState.ToString()
              );
    }

    // Salve in db
    _p2pContext.MessageRepository.Create(msg);
    _p2pContext.Save();
}
```

Comment: You could use AMQP/ rabbitmq or kafka messaging if you want to return a quick 202 response and continue execution of code

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I would like to answer a request, but continue processing code.

Are you sure you want to do this *in ASP.NET?* This is not a situation that ASP.NET (or any web server) was designed to handle.

The classic (correct) way to do this is to queue the work to a persistent queue and have a separate backend process do the actual processing of that work.

There are all kinds of dangers with doing processing inside of ASP.NET outside of a request context. In general, you can't assume that the work will ever actually be done. If you're OK with that (or just like to live dangerously), then you can use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) that goes into more detail.

Comment: Believe me, it's not how I would do it!  I'll read your post.

Comment: Excellent post! I chose to use the Hangfire. Thanks.