# Run code after returning data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTest(Model model)
{
    db.UserOrders.Add(model);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    await PushUtils.SendPush("title" , "message"); // heavy task
    return Ok();
}
```

In this method the user has to wait until the heavy task is executed.
Is there any way to execute this task after returning value to the user?

Comment: this colud help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274096/how-to-answer-a-request-but-continue-processing-code-in-webapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) :

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTest(Model model)
{
    db.UserOrders.Add(model);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => PushUtils.SendPush("title" , "message"),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));

    return Ok();
}
```